# Random Normal Distributed Number Generator

Tags: algorithm

I saw an article saying that one could generate a random normal distributed number by averaging many random numbers (0 to 1).

But how much numbers is "enough"!?

If the amount is too few, the result will be "inaccurate".

But if the amount is too large, the average is almost guaranteed to be the "true average (0.5 in this case)".

So what's the "threshold" I should take to generate a reliable random normal number!?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Look for `Central limit theorem`. Error is proportional to `1/Sqrt(n)`

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49583/gaussian-equivalent-of-convolving-an-image-50-times-with-a-box-filter). The uniform random number is taken from a constant probability density and thus equivalent to the box filter in the question. Adding two random variables will result in a new variable whose probability density is the convolution of the PDFs of the two input variables. Hence, what you do is essentially applying a series of box filters to approximate a Gaussian.

Comment: Back in the 1970’s IBM used 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A usual number is 12 - just add 12 uniform numbers in `[0,1)` and subtract 6 to avoid any bias. The reason is that the variance for the sum is n/12; so by using 12 uniform numbers you avoid the need for scaling. I first noticed the 12 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL - but assume there are more serious libraries using it.

However, what is enough would depend on your needs, and how good the pseudo-random-generator is - and at some point using other formulas will be more efficient.

Comment: Also note that the distribution is bounded by +/-6 sigma, which is not that bad... but not really normal near the edges. I used this a lot in the late 80s, but now I much prefer a box muller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform which is both efficient and accurate,

Comment: @aka.nice I agree that Box-Muller is preferable.

Comment: I thought BM is "also" bounded by ±6 !? And "many people" suggested that the Ziggurat Algorithm is better in this regard!?